# Hangman javascript - my variable for the word guess is apparently undefined and is creating an error in my guessLetter function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, substring

In my guess letter function I am getting errors in the substring and length method for the word variable as it says it is undefined yet it is clearly defined here

```
    var wordsArray = ["monitor", "program", "application", "keyboard", "javascript", "gaming", "network"];
var word;
var goesLeft;
var placeholder;
var input;
var wordLength;
var wordSubstring;
```

To counter this I tried creating variables for word.Substring and word.Length and defining their values in the function and I still got nothing

here's the function for guess letter

```
    function guessLetter()
{
  var correct = 0;

  var inputBox = document.getElementById("guessinput");
  input = inputBox.value;


  console.log(word);

  for (var count = 0; count < wordLength; count++)
  {
    if (input == word.substring(count, count + 1))
    {
      correct++;
      placeholder = placeholder.substring(0, count) + input + placeholder.substring(count + 1, placeholder.length + 1);
      document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = placeholder;
    }
  }

  if (correct == 0)
  {
    goesLeft--;
  }
  var url = document.getElementById("hangimage").src = "http://fetlar.kingston.ac.uk/pp/hangman" + goesLeft + ".jpg";

  if (placeholder == word)
  {
    document.getElementById("hangimage").src = "http://fetlar.kingston.ac.uk/pp/hangman_win.jpg";
    alert("You guessed the word correctly.You win!");
  }

  if (goesLeft == 0)
  {
    alert("You lose");
    newGame();
  }
}
```

The error is coming up here

```
if (input == word.substring(count, count + 1))
```

and also where the for loop is defined

the error says "Error detected during event: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined"

Any ideas?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are missing over half your code. And in your description you have `.` in it. Did you actually mean to have he `.` there?

Comment: shit completely forgot to add where the error was haha sorry hold up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted, you never set word to a value.

```
var word; <-- that is undefined
```

Somewhere in your code I would expect to see

```
currentWord = 0;
word = wordsArray[currentWord];
```